# keyboard shortcuts for the Step, Over, Out buttons in DrRacket?

Tags: debugging, scheme, keyboard-shortcuts, racket

What are the keyboard shortcuts for the Step, Over & Out buttons (When using Debug mode) in DrRacket ?
I could not find them in the Keybindings dialog.

Comment: I'm also interested in this, any luck?

Comment: NO... :-(   I think it wasn't possible in the version I used back than. Maybe today something have changed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is, there aren't any. You could probably build them in, though....

Comment: Thanks, Could you explain or link me to an explanation of how to build keyboard shortcuts in Dr. Racket?

Comment: Sure! Well, I'll give you what I can without spending too much time on it, hope that's okay. ... Okay, I'm back. It looks like the section titled "Defining Custom Shortcuts" is your best introduction. It should be part of your local docs, or you can get it online at http://doc.racket-lang.org/drracket/Keyboard_Shortcuts.html?q=defining%20custom%20shortcuts#%28part._defining-shortcuts%29